# How do I modify the CSS from a specific element in #shadow-root (open)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, dom

Manipulating the style of an element in a "#shadow-root (open)" element seems not possible with CSS only. The shadow-root came there because of a third party JS script and shows a element as an overlay on the page, that I want to remove.

I tried using JavaScript to select and change the style of the element:

```
document.querySelector(".element").style.display = "none"
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

How can I modify the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')", it means that the element you are trying to select with document.querySelector does not exist on the page.

**Try this code below:**

```
const shadowRoot = document.querySelector('#shadow-root-id').shadowRoot;
const element = shadowRoot.querySelector('.element');
element.style.display = 'none';
```

Replace #shadow-root-id with the ID of the #shadow-root element you want to access and .element with the CSS selector for the specific element you want to modify.

If the element you want to modify is deeply nested inside the #shadow-root, you may need to use a more specific CSS selector to target it.